# Volatility of the adjusted prices mean reversion

Tags: volatility

When computing the volatility on the adjusted stocks' prices, would the resulting volatility be mean-reverting? I believe that the volatility of the log returns is mean reverting, but I am not certain about the prices. The returns are basically a first difference of the prices, so they are stationary; but that is not the case with the non-stationary price time series. Would stationarity play a role in mean reversion anyway?